# Error while using triggers and making a table in a variable in mysql under php

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, compiler-errors

Question: Create a database schema in mysql/mariadb of students containing following columns:

1. Name (Variable size string)
2. Date of Birth : DOB (Variable type date)
3. Roll No. (fixed size integer)
4. Registration Number (fixed size string)
5. CPI (0 to 10, floating point)
6. Grade (populate grade based on value in CPI column as per the college rules)

My solution:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

    if (!$con)
    {
      die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error() );
    }

    mysql_select_db("STUDENTS",$con);

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE Information1 (
      Name varchar(25),
      DOB date,
      RollNo int(5),
      RegNum char(7),
      CPI float,
      Grade char(1)
      );

      CREATE TRIGGER a AFTER INSERT ON Information1 
      FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
        IF CPI>=9 THEN
          SET Grade = 'A'
        ELSEIF CPI<9 AND CPI>=7.5 THEN
          SET Grade = 'B'
        ELSEIF CPI<7.5 AND CPI>=6 THEN
          SET Grade = 'C'
        ELSEIF CPI<6 AND CPI>=4 THEN
          SET Grade = 'D'
        ELSE SET Grade = 'F';
      END;


      CREATE TRIGGER a AFTER UPDATE ON Information1 
      FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
        IF NEW.CPI>=9 THEN
          SET NEW.Grade = 'A'
        ELSEIF NEW.CPI<9 AND NEW.CPI>=7.5 THEN
          SET NEW.Grade = 'B'
        ELSEIF NEW.CPI<7.5 AND NEW.CPI>=6 THEN
          SET NEW.Grade = 'C'
        ELSEIF NEW.CPI<6 AND NEW.CPI>=4 THEN
          SET NEW.Grade = 'D'
        ELSE
          SET NEW.Grade = 'F';
        END;
      ";

    mysql_query($sql,$con);

    if (mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
      echo "Table was created"; 
    }
    else echo "Error: " . mysql_error();

    mysql_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The result:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TRIGGER a AFTER INSERT ON Information1 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF CPI>=9 THEN' at line 10
```

What is the cause?

Comment: a) The mysql_* extension is deprecated, see http://docs.php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing b) mysql_query can handle only one statement at a time (not three as in your case)

Comment: I would guess that the trigger name ought to be encased within backticks and perhaps also that it should have a proper name - not simply 'a'. Perphaps "create trigger `trStudents` after update...." and why two triggers the same/virtually the same?

Comment: You're trying to run multiple queries through a single call to mysql_query. You can't do that. You can either split up your SQL to make different calls; or re-write your code using the `mysqli_` library, which lets you use `mysqli_multi_query`.